# fitler table when field matches with other dataset value when no rows in dataset disable filter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have two datasets, one dataset has country field, other dataset has country, I will input country in second dataset, when second dataset has data in it, filter first dataset based on the matched field when second doesn't have data display the default values from first dataset.

Used the following filter in table row group level

```
=IIF(Fields!SecurityDomicile_domicile_country.Value = Lookup(TRUE,TRUE,Fields!cntry_nm.Value, "SelectedCountries"),TRUE,FALSE)  

=

=IIF(CountRows("SelectedCountries")>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

when country input in second dataset filter matches to that. 
when no rows in second dataset display the table as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Filter in group level:

=Fields!SecurityDomicile_domicile_country.Value

In

=IIF(CountRows("SelectedCountries")>0,Lookup(TRUE,TRUE,Country),SecurityDomicile_domicile_country)